# Can someone explain the ULS18u function that appears in the main pages of some site collections?

Tags: 2010, javascript

This function is then used throughout the page for various reasons. Usually it appears as the first line in other java-script functions.

As an example:

```
function toggleBlockOn(elementID) {
      ULS18u:;
      if (document.getElementById(elementID).style.backgroundImage != "") {
      turnOnBlock(elementID);
      }
      }
```

The main interest here is the syntax of that first line. How does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I answered a question on this on Stack Overflow not long ago. Its a debugging/tracing thing.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177001/what-does-this-javascript-code-do/7543257#7543257

Comment: to say the truth there is also a [similar question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21253/structure-of-sharepoint-javascript-functions/21263#21263) here on SharePoint overflow. Nice that you also post here, gived me the opportunity to thank you again for the info (you may had noticed that I linked your answer in that question).

Comment: @SPArchaeologist LOL Nice! Thanks for the credit :-)