# What does ULSxSy:; do in SharePoint JS files?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, out-of-the-box

So I was going through `init.js` and `sp.js` and found out that nearly all of the SharePoint OOB JS functions start with the following line: "**ULSxSy:;**"

For example:

```
function ctxInitItemState(ctxCur)
{ULSxSy:;
    ctxCur.TotalListItems=0;
    ctxCur.CurrentSelectedItems=0;
    ctxCur.LastSelectableRowIdx=0;
    ctxCur.StateInitDone=true;
}
function STSPageUrlValidation(url)
{ULSxSy:;
    return PageUrlValidation(url);
}
```

I could not find any documentation regarding why this might be. Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177001/what-does-this-javascript-code-do/7543257#7543257) was asked on StackOverflow earlier, [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/21263/10610) you'll find a short answer.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177001/what-does-this-javascript-code-do/7543257#7543257) provides the detailed information for your question.

This line

```
{ULSxSy:;
```

is inserted into functions to allow collect diagnostic information on the client which includes the ability to send a JavaScript callstack (including function name, and javascript file) back to the server.

In your case label **ULSxSy** correspond to function declaration

```
function ULSxSy(){
   var o=new Object;
   o.ULSTeamName="Microsoft SharePoint Foundation";
   o.ULSFileName="init.debug.js";
   return o;
}
```