# What is ULS2Vv:;?

Tags: javascript

I see that label in most SharePoint JavaScript libraries. I am curious - what's that used for?

Example:

```
EnsureScriptFunc("clienttemplates.js", "RenderUserFieldWorker", function () {
    ULS2Vv:; // <-- THIS IS THE LABEL IN QUESTION
    var renderCtx = new ContextInfo();
    renderCtx.Templates = {};
...
}
```

Comment: I had a similar question: [structure of sharepoint javascript functions](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21253/structure-of-sharepoint-javascript-functions). There is even a similar question and a detailed answer on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177001/what-does-this-javascript-code-do/7543257#7543257)

Comment: @AnatolyMironov +1 for the reference to my stackoverflow answer ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used to leverage the ULS (Unified Logging Service) capabilities. If you go look in the hive and open any of the `*.js` files, you'll find a similar declaration at the beginning of the file. Each file uses a slightly different declaration, but they all begin with `ULS`.

For example, in SP 2010 `SP.debug.js` this is `ULS5vl` and is declared:

```
function ULS5Vl() {
    var o=new Object;
    o.ULSTeamName="Microsoft SharePoint Foundation";
    o.ULSFileName="SP.debug.js";
    return o;
}
```

The label `ULS5vl:;` throughout the file at the beginning of each function is used to provide trace information.